# How can i prevent player from walking out of the terrain edges?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this case my terrain Transform is: Position X = -250 Y = 0 Z = -250
Rotation 0 0 0 and Scale 1 1 1

The terrain resolution is Width 500 and Length 500 and Height 600

So if i have a ThirdPersonController or a spaceship in some Height when i move the objects to the Terrain edges i want them to stop there and not to continue out of the terrain area.

How can i calculate it in c# script and prevent from the objects to leave the terrain borders ?

[image: Terrain]

Comment: Lots of ways this could be done - why not the tried and true invisible wall approach, if you don't want to create natural barriers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an empty game object and attach a `BoxCollider` to it.
2. Configure the `BoxCollider`: Center: 0, 0, 0. Boundary: 500, 600, 500. `IsTrigger: On`
3. Position it properly on the editor. It will be your restriction area.
4. Attach a script to it, in side your script insert this method

`OnTriggerExit(Collider c) { /* Your code */ }`

Your code will be executed every time a collider leaves your `BoxCollider`. If that is your player, reset it position so that it is inside the restriction area or you could use physics force to pull him back inside.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html

Comment: Ok i did that. But how can i interact connect between the 3 scripts i have ? I have the script that create the clones objects. Script for the waypoints and script for the box collider. Should i open a new question ?

Comment: The part `interact connect between the 3 scripts` confuses me a bit. Generally, script interaction is done via `GetComponent<YourScript>();` but I'm not sure that is what you wanna ask. And anyway, The `OnTriggerExit(Collider c)` method inside `BoxCollider` script is called automatically by Unity so I think you may not need to do anything with it.